# EmEditor Not Opening .XLSX Correctly

Tags: emeditor

I use EmEditor to search within excel files, and text files. Mainly as it is good to right click on a folder, and go "Find Files with Em Editor" and then have them output into one page with all the relevant locations and data pulled out.

However, with some .xlsx files I have, EmEditor is stating:
"Null Characters (00H) Contained in File"

It gives relevant options, none of which open the files correctly (gives corrupted output, all crazy characters etc)

The files open fine in Excel, no corrupt data or anything.

I have 1000's of these files, so is there anyway to open them in EmEditor? I want to search through them

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor is a plain text editor, but Excel (.xlsx) files are not plain text files but binary files.  Therefore, a text editor cannot open Excel (.xlsx) files correctly. You will need to open those Excel (.xlsx) files with Excel, not with text editors including EmEditor.  Alternatively, you can save Excel files as CSV files, and then you can read CSV files with EmEditor.